# PHP dropdown populated from MySQL database won't POST selection to PHP query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, mysqli

Scenario:

I am populating a dropdown menu with data from MySQL database. Upon clicking submit button, script should take the user to the results page and show data based on their selection.

Problem:

User selection is not able to POST to next page for the query. When I hard code an option in that matches one of the dropdown options, the query works fine.

-- This is the dropdown --

```
<div class = "servicelinesearchbox">
   <div class="servicelinesearchbar">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="search_by_service_line.php">
              <select name="service_lines" id ="service_lines" form="service_line_form">
                  <option value = "">---SELECT A SERVICE LINE---</option>

               // THIS OPTION ADDED FOR TESTING, DOES WORK AND POPULATE DATA ON NEXT PAGE --
                  <option value = "Architectural">Architectural</option>
                  <?php
                  $sql = "SELECT service_lines FROM service_lines ORDER BY service_lines";
                  $db = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                  while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
                  echo "<option value='{".$d['service_lines']."}'>".$d['service_lines']."</option>";
                  }
                  ?>
               </select>  
               <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">SEARCH</button>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

-- This is the part of the results page that uses POST data to run the query --

```
<?php

include "config.php";

if (isset($_POST["save"])> 0) {
    $service_lines = htmlspecialchars($_POST['service_lines']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subconsultants WHERE service_lines LIKE '$service_lines'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: *"User selection is not able to POST to next page for the query."* - Can you clarify the specific debugging observations you're making and specifically what is failing?  Is the form not posting **at all**?  Is it posting, but not with the value(s) you expect?  Is it posting the expected value(s) but something isn't working as expected in the server-side code?  Something else?

Comment: Do you see the options in the menu? If not, do you see them when you do `View Source`?

Comment: Why are you putting `{}` around the values? `value='{".$d['service_lines']."}'`

Comment: You don't have those curly braces in `value = "Architectural"`, so I think that's why it works and the dynamic ones don't. Get rid of them.

Comment: You should also use `=` rather than `LIKE` when looking up the consultants, since it doesn't have any wildcards.

Comment: @Barmar Removing the curly braces worked. Also changed LIKE back to =. I originally had it like that but changed it to see if it made a difference.

Also, could you give me an example of how to use prepared statements and parameterized queries instead of concatenation please? I rarely if ever do front-end work

Comment: The examples are in the link in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Added more information as requested by @zth_codes**

in line:

```
echo "<option value='{".$d['service_lines']."}'>".$d['service_lines']."</option>";
```

curly braces are no needed: remove them

in line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subconsultants WHERE service_lines LIKE '$service_lines'";
```

must be added `%` to let the LIKE operator work: `LIKE '%$service_lines%'`

and using paramters instead of string concatenation will prevent SQL injections

##### Example of using prepared statements and parameters in the query and further recommendations

A possible example for prepared statement with parameters can be this:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM subconsultants WHERE service_lines = ?';
    
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['service_lines']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
}
```

It's a bit more verbose but avoids SQL injection.

I also replaced the `LIKE` operator with the `=` operator in the query, since it doesn't seem to me that partial searches are needed: this way you will also benefit from any indexes on the search column

Another tip: don't use double quotes in strings unless necessary: ​​double quotes always make the string go through special character handling and variable expansion.

Finally, I advise against closing the PHP code with the `?>` tag if there are no further lines of HTML in the PHP file: any empty and invisible lines in the code after the `?>` tag are interpreted as (unwanted) HTML lines

Comment: Removing the curly braces solved the problem. Could you give me an example of how to use parameters instead of string concatenation please? I'm very new to PHP, I mainly do back-end coding but had to create this tool for work as I'm the only developer currently.

Comment: @zth_codes I've added an example and further recommendations in my answer as requested

Comment: thank you very much. Also, I just went to keep working on this today and now it no longer works? It is telling me undefined array key for this line:

$service_lines = htmlspecialchars($_POST['service_lines']);

But yesterday it worked?

Comment: @zth_codes - Have you changed the name of *select input*?  
- Did you add at least one option to your *select input*?  - Also remove *form* attribute from *select input*.
(If you use prepared statements with parameters you don't need anymore to apply htmlspecialchars() to your input)

Comment: I removed the form attribute and it fixed it, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @zth_codes glad to have been of help.